# Is there a way to create multiple filters while using query function in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Link to Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kC9086eSa-YO1EWEhDvdKGopgyeyDwbw8xCuejnyU7w/edit?usp=sharing

I am currently trying to create a tool that allows me to search for keywords out of an entire list I generated in a different tab. I want it to pay attention to different types of filters. It has the following table to enter search criteria:

[Keyword Explorer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrvMj.png)

The query box in the table is the first filter I want to run. In the example, all keywords contain the word "onesie." For example, if I type "baby" in the query, then it would look at the filter type which is a dropdown menu. In the image below, I am selecting "contains" as the filter type.

[Query and Filter Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lwo7.png)

In the table, I also want the functionality to add several "AND" and "OR" filters.

Here is a layout of the entire table:

[Keyword Explorer Tab in Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRD3t.png)

Columns B through D are all just VLOOKUPS of Column A. The formula for the entire tab is in A2. The formula is currently 
=QUERY('Onesie US Info'!A2:A,
 "select A 
  where lower(A) "&G4&" '"&G2&"'
    and (lower(A) "&G4&" '"&I2&"') or (lower(A) "&G4&" '"&J2&"') 
  ", 0)

But it isn't working. I would like to know if it's possible to get the filtering table to work the way I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps like this:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY('Onesie US Info'!A2:A,
 "select A 
  where lower(A) "&B2&" '"&I2&"' 
    and lower(A) "&B2&" '"&I3&"'
    and lower(A) "&B2&" '"&I4&"'", 0),
 "select Col1 
  where lower(Col1) "&B2&" '"&J2&"'
     or lower(Col1) "&B2&" '"&J3&"'
     or lower(Col1) "&B2&" '"&J4&"'", 0), )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. My only question is, is there a way to still have C1 be useful in determining the initial filter for the results below? So it would be C1 AND I2?

Comment: not rly sure I get you but I guess yes, why not... you can add C1 to it too

Comment: I added some comments to the Google Sheet that may clarify my initial question. Also, thank you for everything already. If this is too much to ask, don't worry about it. What you did is a huge improvement.